# Declaring a Maven project dependecy on artefact in an Ivy repo

Tags: maven, maven-2, ivy

I have a Maven 2 project and now need to declare a dependency on artefacts which are kept in an Ivy repository.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Ivy Maven Plugin:

https://github.com/remis-thoughts/ivy-maven-plugin

"A plugin to add apache Ivy dependencies to a Maven project. This is a fork of Evgeny Goldin's Ivy Maven Plugin that fixes support for transitive dependencies."

(Note that the early comments below refer to Evgeny Goldin's Ivy Maven Plugin - looks like this fork fixes the problem I was having).

Comment: I'm moving this from the answer into a comment, as it was probably my mistake I couldn't get it working and I don't want to put others off trying it: "I did struggle to get this working, however - although I could see the dependencies being resolved as expected, the compile phase wasn't seeing the classes from the Ivy repo. Perhaps I was running too old a version of Maven."

Comment: Sajan: I could see Maven fetching the dependencies from the Ivy repo, but the classes in those jars were not found by the compiler, so it looked as though the classpath was not being set up correctly. Unfortunately I don't have that project set up with the plugin anymore to get any more details from. As mentioned above - it was probably my mistake or old Maven version, so definitely worth trying the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a rather opinionated framework, so only supports Maven repositories.

Do you have any control over the ivy repository? The best solution would be to migrate it's contents over to a Maven repository manager like Nexus (Artifactory, Apache Archiva are other options).

There are lots of advantages to having a repository manager:

- Support for all build clients, Maven, Ivy, Gradle, etc
- Ability to search for artifacts
- ..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up migrating this project to [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/). By default Gradle uses the same project layout as Maven, so the migration was very simple.

Gradle allows you to [declare dependencies across many types of repositories](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec%3arepositories):

- Maven
- Ivy
- Flat file

So you could have some dependencies in a Maven repo, others in an Ivy repo and others in a project lib directory (shock, horror!).

Highly recommended.